# How to do a query on has_and_belongs_to in Rails with AND across the join instead of OR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

This may be a simple issue but I'm struggling. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a class, let's call it `Car` that HABTM `Features`. So:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :features
end

class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
end
```

Let's say I created the following data:

```
bumper = Feature.create(name: "Bumper")
windshield = Feature.create(name: "Windshield")
Car.create(name: "Toyota", features: [bumper, windshield])
```

So now I have a single car instance that has two features.

Let's say someone passes in (through a web form, for example) a list of features. I want to do a query to only find cars that have ALL the features passed in.

So if the feature list passed in was: `["Bumper", "Brakes"]` then it should NOT find that "Toyota" car. But if the feature list was `["Bumper"]` it should, or if the feature list was `["Windshield","Bumper"]` it should.

This clearly doesn't work because it's an 'OR':
`Car.joins(:features).where(features: {name: ["Bumper","Brakes"]})`
That returns the "Toyota" car because "Bumper" matches a feature joined to that car. What I want it to do, in this case, is return `[]` (no cars).

How do I set up a Rails query for this case?

Note: the number of features is variable for a given car and the number of feature lists passed in is also variable. I just want the passed-in feature list to be ANDed for the features and only return cars that have ALL the features based on the feature list.

I know this is probably easy but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from an easier case, `Feature` has a `car_id` field, `Car has_many features`.

Then you could query like this:

1. Use [ARRAY_AGG](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg-function/) aggregate function to return a `subquery`, each row have all the `feature names` of a `car`, e.g. `[{car_id: 1, names: ["Bumper", "Brakes"]}, ...]`
2. `Car` `JOIN` `Feature` by `subquery`, then filter `cars` with [@>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator.

```rb
# Example code, may need to tweak a bit
sql = Feature.select(car_id, ARRAY_AGG(name) as names)
             .group(:car_id)
             .order(:car_id)
             .to_sql

Car.joins("INNER JOIN (#{sql}) AS features ON cars.id = features.user_id")
   .where("features.names @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", names)
```

In your case, you used `has_and_belongs_to_many`, so you need to tweak a bit to work with the `joining table`, e.g. `car_features`.